# Unable to loop inside a call to XML::Generator

Tags: xml, perl, perl-module

I am trying to use a `for` loop to put each item from array `@cpuinfo` into a separate `<cpu>`  element
in an XML document
using [XML::Generator](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Generator).

```
# @cpuinfo contain cpu information of multiple cpu's
use XML::Generator;

my $gen = XML::Generator->new( 'escape' => 'always', 'pretty' => 10 );

my $xml = $gen->servers(
   $gen->server(

      $gen->cpuinfo(

         foreach $r (@cpuinfo){
            $gen->cpu;
            (  {  $gen->cpu( @cpuinfo[$r] );
               }
            )
         }

      )
   ),
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. I've fixed the broken markup in the code in your question. Next time please reread your post before submitting it.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. It's not clear if those are from copying it to the question or if they are there in your real code. You should [edit] your question and include the actual code you are running, with the actual indentation and everything. To show code as code in Stack Overflow, select all of it and press ctrl + k on your keyboard or click the {} button above the editor. Please also show us an example of what `@cpuinfo` could contain, what the XML it generates now looks like and what kind of XML you are expecting.

Comment: thank you simbabque

Comment: Yes, I think you may need to backtrack here, and give input data and desired output - I think this can be done better, but without knowing these things I can't help.

Comment: Well done on that edit, but you still have a `;` in the middle of your loop. You can even see that from the way you indented your code (which is good, btw). There's `$gen->cpu;`, followed by an open paren `(`. This essentially calls `$gen->cpu` without args, then creates an empty list that contains a block with one statement in it, which should be a syntax error. You should really turn on `use strict` and `use warnings`. You also have `@cpuinfo[$r]`, which should be `$cpuinfo[$r]` The sigil needs to refer to what that value is, and array elements are scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be at all familiar with Perl, and this isn't the place for a tutorial, but most languages don't allow you to put an executable loop inside a parameter list. What you need is a call to `map`, which "maps" one list of data into another. In this case it maps the list of text items in `@cpuinfo` to a list of `XML::Generator` objects that each represent a `<map>` element

Remember that you *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write, and declare every variable with `my` as close as possible to its first point of use, preferably at the point it is defined

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::Generator;

my @cpuinfo = qw/ A B C /;

my $gen = XML::Generator->new( escape => 'always', pretty => 2 );

my $xml = $gen->servers(
    $gen->server(
        $gen->cpuinfo(
            map { $gen->cpu($_) } @cpuinfo
        )
    )
);

print $xml, "\n";
```

#### output

```xml
<servers>
  <server>
    <cpuinfo>
      <cpu>A</cpu>
      <cpu>B</cpu>
      <cpu>C</cpu>
    </cpuinfo>
  </server>
</servers>
```